# Embedded flash object shows black bars

Tags: html, flash

I've embedded a flash object in a form, and anchored it to the 4 borders. And when I resize the window, the flash application resizes too... but it tries to keep its proportions, showing unaesthetic black bars instead of change its width/length proportion.

How can I change this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [scale - Possible values: showall, noborder, exactfit, noscale.](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html)
>   try `<param name="scale" value="exactfit">`